# How do you write a word in both singular and plural form?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I want to write a word in both singular and plural form, without having to write the word twice. Here is an example sentence using both a singular and plural:

"She had to make the choice or choices"

Can it be written like this instead:

"She had to make the choice/s"

I need this for a page title in a technical article, so I do not have a lot of freedom in sentence structure.

Comment: You should not use abbreviations of that sort in technical articles.

Comment: Perhaps technical article was not the right term.

I know that abbreviations can be used in what I am writing, so I would like to know if a noun can be abbreviated in that way?

Comment: The more customary abbreviation style in informal texts is the parenthesis here: *choice(s)*.

Comment: It's not so easy when spelling changes more radically, as with _daisy/daisies_.

Comment: Using "choice(s)" works. How about using "make a choice" (instead of "the choice")?

Comment: I think "choice(s)" or "choice/s" such as we might use here are part of an informal short-hand, not a part of proper punctuation.

I can't imagine how you could be planning to use that for a title, let alone in a technical article, without knowing how many choices she had.

If I had my druthers - all one of them - my surmise would be that the meaning is really "one or more" which, surely, should be plural, so "choices".

Answer (score 0):

How about using the word 'selection'? As this word conveys the idea more of a range of choices, you might be able to get away with using selection on its own, avoiding having to say choice/s.  You won't need to say selection/s as selection already means 'one or more choices.'

It says at the link below 'Selection is the act of selecting one or more people or things from a group.'

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/selection